# Постоянное соединение клиент-сервер

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, сокет, uwp

Здравствуйте. Хочу на основе сделать просто постоянное соединение между клиентом и сервером. Но возникает много вопросов. Я так понимаю, TcpListener в режиме прослушки позволяет получить TcpClient, с которым можно непосредственно взаимодействовать? Но после подключения и обмена сообщениями он закрывается. А мне нужно поддерживать активное соединение, да еще к тому же на стороне и клиента, и сервера реагировать на каждое новое сообщение, которое приходит с какой-либо стороны.

```
public class Server
{
    private TcpListener serverListener = null;
    private NetworkCredential authCredential = null;
    private int port;
    public TcpClient client = null;

    public Server(int port, string userName, string password)
    {
        authCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        this.port = port;
    }

    public async void StartServer()
    {
        IPAddress serverIp = IPAddress.Any;
        serverListener = new TcpListener(serverIp, port);
        serverListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (client = await serverListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
                {
                    using (NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream, Encoding.UTF8, false,2048, true))
                        {
                            string receivedMessage = streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        }
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write("какой-то текст");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Закрывается, потому как using (client = await serverListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()) - а зачем его сразу закрывать, если он еще нужен? Получили клиента, сохранили и общайтесь по его потоку.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже понял одну ошибку, using (network stream...) высвобождает сам клиент. Теперь есть постоянное соединение. Как теперь дать понять и как клиенту, так и серверу, что им пришло сообщение? Или мне на уровне клиента периодически просто проверять не пришло ли там чего-нибудь от сервера?

Comment: Единственная возможность понять, что что-то пришло - постоянно читать из потока, который дает TcpClient. Можно асинхронно, а можно блокирующе.

Comment: То есть и в реальных приложениях, онлайн играх тоже идёт постоянная проверка таким образом или есть может что-нибудь, что умеет уведомлять клиент а том, что к нему пришло сообщение? Может не сокет, а другое что?

Comment: В потоках нет понятия сообщений - данные просто льются. Сообщение есть сущность приложения, и дело приложения правильно смаппировать сообщение в/из потока. Опять же - ReadAsync для асинхронного чтения - разве это постоянная проверка? Я как-то писал [клиента](https://github.com/Caraul/FabricAdcHub/blob/master/FabricAdcHub.TcpServer/AdcClient.cs) - можно глянуть для примера как читаются строки из потока. Про реальные приложения не скажу - слышал, что там вообще  общаются по UDP, но вот потоками или датаграммами - я пас.

Comment: ReadAsync работает прекрасно до первого сообщения с сервера, а потом в цикле while(true) { await ..ReadAsync()  } начинает как бешенный что-то принимать, хотя никаких больше данных не приходит. и процессор на 30% постоянно загружает. Фигня какая-то.

Comment: Если ReadAsync возвращает 0 как длину данных - TCP-соединение разорвано. См. например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685670/tcpclient-networkstream-readasync-c-sharp

Comment: Да тут скорее всего для того, что мне надо надо развернуть WebSocketServer. И опять вопрос: вот у меня есть прорамма. Она поддерживает динамические библиотеки (с++). Есть бибилотека на плюсах, которая является по сути загрузчиком (прослойкой) между моими библиотеками с# и программой. Так вот этот веб-сервер мне надо интегрировать в мою с# библиотеку. Всем остальным будет программа управлять через свои события. Я смогу это реализовать?

Comment: На это лучше написать отдельный развернутый вопрос.